# Linq merging results

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

I'm working with a list within a list. This is how I'm currently searching:

```
var tags = from fd in BigList
           from tag in fd.Tags
           where tag.Id == selectedTag.Id ||
                 tag.Id == ID.TIMESTAMP
           select new { fd.Name, tag.Id, tag.Value };
```

I then iterate over the result-set and remembering when Timestamp pops up for the next entry, needless to say this is sloppy and I'm positive there's a better way using Linq, I just can't seem to find the syntax.

Here's some sample output (`Id` indicates what type of data is stored inside e.g. a timestamp):

```
Name | Id | Value
-----|----|----------
0000 | 1  | <timestamp>
0000 | 2  | 1.2
...
9999 | 1  | <timestamp>
9999 | 2  | 6.3
```

I need all instances where `Id = selectedTag.Id`. I just want 1 list with `Name`, `Id`, `Value` and `Timestamp`, but the problem is my above attempt returns 2 entries for every item (1 for timestamp and 1 for the value). Is there a way to do this using Linq? Preferably using query syntax! :)

Comment: It returns a list with 2 entries for each item (1 for timestamp and 1 for the value I'm looking up) so unless I'm missing something obvious, there's still quite a bit of leg-work to retrieve the timestamp for every entry.

Comment: You just need `from tag in fd.Tags` in there twice -- once with `where tag.Id == selectedTag.Id` and once with `where tag.Id == ID.TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: @Gabe: I believe I tried that too already (via 2 separate queries) ? But then what? Iterate both simultaneously? Concat them?

Comment: What do you want in your Value column when you have two matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it as a single query:

```
var tags = from fd in BigList
           from tag in fd.Tags
           where tag.Id == selectedTag.Id
           from tag2 in fd.Tags
           where tag.Id == ID.TIMESTAMP
           select new { fd.Name, id = tag.Value, timestamp = tag2.Value };
```

Here's a way to do it by joining two queries:

```
var tags = from fd in BigList
           from tag in fd.Tags
           where tag.Id == selectedTag.Id
           select new { fd.Name, id = tag.Value };
var tag2 = from fd in BigList
           from tag2 in fd.Tags
           where tag.Id == ID.TIMESTAMP
           select new { fd.Name, timestamp = tag2.Value };
var data = from id in tags
           join ts in tag2 on id.Name equals ts.Name
           select new { id.Name, id.id, ts.timestamp };
```